# Two frameworks (or bundles) with the same class name, interface and implementation, are loaded into a runtime. What happens?

Tags: objective-c, c, dynamic, runtime

Say I dynamically load a framework via `dlopen()`, or load a bundle via `[NSbundle load]` that have a class with the same name as one already in the runtime. What happens to the runtime? What class definition wins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the second will win.  However, it's almost certainly an implementation detail that is subject to change at Apple's whim.

Comment: Interesting. So the second class definition will what, override the original? What about existing instances at that time? It's weird, I can't find anything concrete on this...

Comment: You won't because it's all implementation detail, and not explicit design.  It can change at any time.  Every instance of a class has a pointer to the class's definition (the `isa` pointer).  If the definition is overwritten, the `isa` pointer will simply point to the new definition, and the existing instances will behave like the "new" class.  If the new definition isn't at the same location and the `isa` pointers aren't updated, chaos will probably ensue.

Comment: Thanks for the further elaboration! That clears things up a bit I've marked yours as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly undefined behavior.  In fact, if you load a bundle via the `NSBundle` API, it will actually give an error message that says it detected the conflict, and the behavior is undefined as to how it handles the conflict.

The basic rule is to not do that. ;-)